# Which button is pressed in grid view

Tags: iphone, ios, gridview, uibutton

Evening All

I have the following code to fill in a grid of buttons, but how do I detect which button has been selected and pass the button image on another controller

```
i =0; 
int i1=0; 
while(i<n){ 
int yy = 4 +i1*79; 
for(int j=0; j<4;j++){ 
if (i>=n) break; 
CGRect rect; 
rect = CGRectMake(4+79*j, yy, 75, 75); 
UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect]; 
[button setFrame:rect]; 

id item = [items objectAtIndex:i]; 
NSString *imageLink = [item objectForKey:@"link"]; 

UIImage *buttonImageNormal=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURLURLWithString: imageLink]]]; 

[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
button.tag =i; 
NSLog(@"index: %i", i); 
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, one comment for your code.. It is bad practice to use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] just in the main thread, because it is synchronous.. You may receive bad performance with this approach. It's better to use UIImageView to display image from URL (it has method setImageWithURL, that loads data asynchronously).

Comment: Thank you for the tip Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give each button a tag, and then use the `-(void)buttonPressed:` posted earlier. With that function, you could do something like:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)senderButton 
{
    if (senderButton.tag == 0) {
         // perform segue
    } else if (senderButton.tag == 1) {
         // perform other segue
    }
}
```

And so on, and so forth.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You will obtain pressed button as an argument to the callback method (buttonPressed:).
Just implement it in such manner:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)senderButton {

    UIImage *image = [senderButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //use image:)
}
```

Comment: I know that, I have a grid of buttons, each button is an image from an array so similar to the Photos app, I'd like to know how to find out with button is pressed so I can push that buttons images to another viewController